# Countable sup property of extended measurable functions

Tags: measure-theory, order-theory, measurable-functions

Let $(S,\Sigma,\mu)$ a $\mu$-finite measure space. Denote by $\bar{L}^0(\Sigma)$ the set of extended-real valued $\Sigma$-measurable functions. Does this set have the countable sup property when endowed with the pointwise $\mu$-a.e. order?

Answer (score 2):

See e.g. [1] for the basic definitions  (Note that functions that agree $\mu$-a.e. are identified.) Given a collection $H$ of extended real-valued measurable functions with supremum $h^* in the  a.e. pointwise partial order, we will  find a countable sub-collection with the same  supremum  in this partial order.

Let $G=\{\arctan\circ h : h \in H\}$ with the convention that $\arctan(\pm \infty)=\pm \pi/2$.
Let $F$ be the collection of pointwise maxima of finite subsets of $G$.   Denote  $M_F:=\sup_{f \in F} \int f\, d\mu$. There must exist a sequence $f_k\in F$ such that $\int f_k\, d\mu \to M_F$ as $ k \to \infty$.
Each $f_k$ is a pointwise maximum $f_k=\max_{j \in J_k} g_{kj}$ with $g_{kj} \in G$ and $J_k$ finite. Write $F_k=\max\{f_1,\cdots ,f_k\}$.
Define $g^*(x)=\sup_k f_k(x)=\sup_k F_k$, a pointwise supremum. Clearly $\int g^* \, d\mu=M_F$ and $g^*$ is a  supremum of the countable collection
$G_0=\{g_{kj} : k\ge 1,\; j \in J_k\} $ in the given partial order. For each $g$ in $G$ we have $\int g \vee F_n \, d\mu\le M_F$ so $\int g \vee g^* \,d\mu   \le M_F$. Thus $g \le g^*$ a.e.  It follows that $\tan \circ \, g^*$ is a supremum of $H$ which must agree a.e. with $h^*$. Therefore $h^*$ is an a.e. pointwise sup of the countable collection $\tan \circ \, G_0$.

[1]  Luxemburg, W. A. J. "On some order properties of Riesz spaces and their relations." Archiv der Mathematik 19, no. 5 (1968): 488-493.